# Login con dos tablas

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

Quiero lograr un Login donde el usuario deba ingresar Email, contraseña y un código para acceder a un sitio.
Logre que tome el email y contraseña pero no logro el código.
El código se encuentra en otra tabla.

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM w_usuarios WHERE email = '$email' UNION FROM w_codigoDto WHERE codigo = '$codigo'";


$result = $conexion->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {     }


  $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
 // if (password_verify($password, $row['password'])) { 
if ($pass==$row['pass']) { 


    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['start'] = time();
    $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (5 * 60);

    echo "Bienvenido! " . $_SESSION['username'];
    echo "<br><br><a href=panel-control.php>Panel de Control</a>"; 
    header('Location: http://localhost/my_website/panel-control.php');//redirecciona a la pagina del usuario

 } else { 
   echo "Email o Contraseña estan incorrectos.";

   echo "<br><a href='login.html'>Volver a Intentarlo</a>";
 }
```

Comment: Lee sobre inyección SQL y cómo evitarla en PHP. El código compartido es vulnerable a ese tipo de ataques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te hace falta un select en tu query

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;

SELECT * FROM w_usuarios WHERE email = '$email' UNION SELECT codigo FROM w_codigoDto WHERE codigo = '$codigo'
```